# Facebook Like doesn't show on profile

Tags: facebook-like

On my website I have like buttons. When someone likes something it displays the link on their Facebook profile but it doesn't show on their wall when it should. I can't figure out why this is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should look into the [send button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/send/).
You can also get a version of the like button with a send button attached.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook like is just the social plugin from Facebook. It can't post users' likes to their wall. You can post to their wall only from Facebook Application API.

Comment: its not a user but just the general pulbic likes something on my site it just posts on their profile and doesn't display on their wall. so the facebook api enables the like to post to their wall as well as their profile?

Comment: It is really nice question. I can't answer now. We need to do more research on FB plugin and API. Thanks.